# Make flag history searchable

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-history

### Context

I have a very large flagging history, numbering well over thousands of flags. A lot of those flags are for plagiarized answers that I've found.

Today I discovered that someone I had previously flagged for plagiarism a month ago, had just plagiarized yet another answer last week. As a matter of fact, this particular user seems very familiar, and I think it might be because I had flagged him for plagiarism *last year* as well.

However, because I have such a large flagging history, it would be very tedious and time consuming to look through each page of flag history manually. Each page of flag history contains 50 flagged posts/comments, and I have many, many such pages.

### Request

It would be helpful (to me at least, not sure about other users) if it were possible to search my flagging history based on:

1. Flag comment text (when you use the "Other" flag option), and/or
2. User id of flagged post/comment.

If I were able to search my flag history based on user id, then I would be able to very easily verify whether or not I had actually flagged this one particular user for plagiarism last year as well.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what does it matter if you've flagged them last year or last month etc... you're still going to end up flagging that it's plagiarised anyway, right?

Comment: @JonClements yes, but I figured it would be helpful to you mods if I point out repeat offenders when I come across them. Is it not?

Comment: For this specific example - if you have an inkling this is repeat behaviour, you can add your suspicion in the flag - mods can look at all flags related to a user and confirm if that's the case (eg: just add a "I believe this is repeat behaviour" to your flag reason)

Comment: As to the FR - I don't see any harm in being able to search other flags, but I imagine indexing them, the UI components to make them searchable and the number of people that would use it (if they had so many to require it) in the number of cases it could be useful - it's going to be a no-go.